# summing array of doubles with large value span : proper algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, floating-point

I have an algorithm where I need to sum (a lot of time) double numbers ranging in the e-40 to the e+40.

Array Example (randomly dumped from real application):

```
-2.06991e-05 
7.58132e-06 
-3.91367e-06 
7.38921e-07 
-5.33143e-09
-4.13195e-11 
4.01724e-14 
6.03221e-17 
-4.4202e-20
6.58873 
-1.22257
-0.0606178 
0.00036508 
2.67599e-07 
0
-627.061
-59.048 
5.92985 
0.0885884
0.000276455 
-2.02579e-07
```

It goes without saying the I am aware of the rounding effect this will cause, I am trying to keep it under control : the final result should not have any missing information in the fractional part of the double or, if not avoidable result should be at least n-digit accurate (with n defined). End result needs something like 5 digits plus exponent.

After some decent thinking, I ended up with following algorithm :

- Sort the array so that the largest absolute value comes first, closest to zero last.
- Add everything in a loop

The idea is that in this case, any cancellation of large values (negatives and positive) will not impact latter smaller values.
In short :

- (10e40 - 10e40) + 1 = 1 : result is as expected
- (1 + 10e-40) - 10e40 = 0 : not good

I ended up using std::multiset (benchmark on my PC gave 20% higher speed with long double compared to normal doubles - I am fine with doubles resolution) with a custom sort function using std:fabs.

It's still quite slow (it takes 5 seconds to do the whole thing) and I still have this feeling of "you missed something in your algo". Any recommandation :

1. for speed optimization. Is there a better way to sort the intermediate products ? Sorting a set of 40 intermediate results (typically) takes about 70% of the total execution time.
2. for missed issues. Is there a chance to still lose critical data (one that should have been in the fractional part of the final result) ?

---

On a bigger picture, I am implementing real coefficient polynomial classes of pure imaginary variable (electrical impedances : Z(jw)). Z is a big polynom representing a user defined system, with coefficient exponent ranging very far.
The "big" comes from adding things like Zc1 = 1/jC1w to  Zc2 = 1/jC2w :
    Zc1 + Zc2 = (C1C2(jw)^2 + 0(jw))/(C1+C2)(jw)

In this case, with C1 and C2 in nanofarad (10e-9), C1C2 is already in 10e-18 (and it only started...)

my sort function use a manhattan distance of complex variables (because, mine are either pure real or pure imaginary) :

```
struct manhattan_complex_distance
{
        bool operator() (std::complex<long double> a, std::complex<long double> b)
        {
            return std::fabs(std::real(a) + std::imag(a)) > std::fabs(std::real(b) + std::imag(b));
        }
};
```

and my multi set in action :

```
std:complex<long double> get_value(std::vector<std::complex<long double>>& frequency_vector)
{
    //frequency_vector is precalculated once for all to have at index n the value (jw)^n. 
    std::multiset<std::complex<long double>, manhattan_distance> temp_list;   
    for (int i=0; i<m_coeficients.size(); ++i)
    {
        //   element of :       ℝ         *         ℂ
        temp_list.insert(m_coeficients[i] * frequency_vector[i]);
    }
    std::complex<long double> ret=0;
    for (auto i:temp_list)
    {
        // it is VERY important to start adding the big values before adding the small ones.
        // in informatics, 10^60 - 10^60 + 1 = 1; while 1 + 10^60 - 10^60 = 0. Of course you'd expected to get 1, not 0.
        ret += i;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The project I have is c++11 enabled (mainly for improvement of the math lib and complex number tools)

ps : I refactored the code to make is easy to read, in reality all complexes and long double names are template : I can change the polynomial type in no time or use the class for regular polynomial of ℝ

Comment: It would be nice if you would at least leave a link to a [MCVE] to enable anyone willing to answer your questions to play with the code.

Comment: You may find better performance storing the data in a vector and then sorting it once the vector is filled.  It is much more cache friendly and it should still have the same complexity.

Comment: @NathanOliver : I tried benchmarking both option, using vector + post insert sorting took 15% more time in average (50 runs). It could be due to the fact that the array remain small in size : few cache access are to be expected. the function, on the other hand, is called _very_ often.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : A minimal code is not really an option. The whole project to generate and manipulate polynomial is not quite small... moreover, there is not really a "problem" that I could point to because it works like a charm (at least until now). This question is about algorithmic recommendations.

Comment: @MrBuisson I said _at least **post a link**_. Put something working into a Online IDE like [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/).

Comment: @MrBuisson Also note questions about improving already working code may be better placed at [SE Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but be assured they want to see your full code as well.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [Kahan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm)?

Comment: @MrBuisson  For the accurate evaluation of the polynomial, consider the [compensated Horner scheme](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0610122.pdf), also available in a [variant for complex numbers](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~graillat/papers/rnc08.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [GuyGreer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1277769/guygreer) suggested, you can use [Kahan summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm):

```
double sum = 0.0;
double c = 0.0;
for (double value : values) {
    double y = value - c;
    double t = sum + y;
    c = (t - sum) - y;
    sum = t;
}
```

EDIT: You should also consider using [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) to evaluate the polynomial.

```
double value = coeffs[degree];
for (auto i = degree; i-- > 0;) {
    value *= x;
    value += coeffs[i];
}
```

Comment: That was indeed the kind of think I was looking for.

Comment: At the very least I have now a todo with Kahan summation. As for Horner method, I need a bit more time to assimilate the delta in multiplication / addition compared to a pre calculated vector of powers. I calculate about 100 polynomials for each frequency : pre calculating "could" also be valid. Comparing performance is at least a good exercise. In any case, this is valuable information.

Comment: Implementation feedback : a pure Kahan summation works for real and complex numbers and was the first step of the implementation. Because it get rid at once of the vector thing and the ordering (which was quite costly), it improved adding speed by a factor of 4.5 ! time spent in adding is now only 45% of total time (used to be slightly above 80%). this is great ! Let's see if I can get it further down.

Comment: @MrBuisson Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Sorting the data is on the right track.  But you definitely should be summing from smallest magnitude to largest, not from largest to smallest.  Summing from largest to smallest, by the time you get to the smallest, aligning the next value with the current sum is liable to cause most or all of the bits of the next value to 'fall off the end'.  Summing instead from smallest to largest, the smallest values get a chance to accumulate a decent-sized sum, for which more bits will get into the largest.  Combined with Kahan summation, that should yield a fairly accurate sum.

Comment: I have a finite sum of double, I don't expect that adding any amount of small value could ever reach the range of the large ones. Wouldn't it fail with following values : 1 + 1^30 - 1^30 ?

Comment: I tried it just now :
        volatile double a = 1e30, b = -1e30, c = 1;
        qDebug()<<"(a+b)+c"<<(a+b)+c; //print 1
        qDebug()<<"(c+b)+a"<<(c+b)+a; //print 0 : catastrophic cancellation

Answer (score 1):

First: have your math keep track of error.  Replace your doubles with error-aware types, and when you add or multiply together two doubles it also calculates the *maximium error*.

This is about the only way you can guarantee that your code produces accurate results while being reasonably fast.

Second, don't use a `multiset`.  The associative containers are not for sorting, they are for *maintaining a sorted collection*, while being able to incrementally add or remove elements from it efficiently.

The ability to add/remove elements incrementally means it is node-based, and node-based means it is slow in general.

If you simply want a sorted collection, start with a `vector` then `std::sort` it.

Next, to minimize error, keep a list of positive and negative elements.  Start with zero as your sum.  Now pick the smallest of either the positive or negative elements such that the total of your sum and that element is closest to zero.

Do so with elements that calculate their error bounds.

At the end, determine if you have 5 digits of precision, or not.

These error-propogating doubles should be ideally used as early on in the algorithm as possible.

Comment: There is now two recommendation to drop the multiset, which makes me wonder if I did a fair comparison test (eg: vector sort used lambda function & vector was a QT Qvector, not and std::vector). I will follow up on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already mentioned Kahan summation, which is generally the best option when accuracy of the result is of much higher concern than efficiency. But when thinking about accurate summation, another option you should consider is [pairwise summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_summation). It's about as fast as the naive algorithm, or even faster if you consider parallellizing it, and don't set the base case too high. And, while Kahan summation has an error bound of `2*eps + O(n * eps^2)`, which is constant in practice, pairwise summation has `O(eps * log(N))`, which is pretty close.